# passing all table data from jsp to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I have user editable table at front end. when user click process button, i am doing form validation in jquery from there i am passing flow to servlet, So i have to pass the bunch of table data to servlet. Some one please suggest me on how to pass all table data in ajax call. Currenly i have a piece of code which contains table data in array where i can get as each cell values. instead of that i wanna pass it in row manner

```js
var InspTableArray = [];
   $("#tab_logic tr.data").map(function (index, tr) {
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                var $data = $(this).html();
                 if($(this).find("select").length > 0) {
                        var $x = $(this).find("select").val();                    
                    }else{
                   var $x = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();
                }
                 InspTableArray.push($x);
            });   
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using jQuery post method https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/:

```
$.post('/url/to/page', {'arrayFieldName': InspTableArray} );
```

Comment: Thanks for ur input. so can we get the same in servlet using getParameter?

Comment: I'd rather use the getParameterValues. Plus jquery seems to append [] to the field name, so the code should look like this: String[] arrayFieldName = req.getParameterValues("arrayFieldName[]");